# validations on uploaded files using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the below JQuery code , i 'm validating the uploaded files :

```
        $(".inputFiles").on("change", function(e) {
        var uploadedFiles = e.originalEvent.target.files;
        var fileSize = 100;
        var fileType = ["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"];

        alert("length" + uploadedFiles.length)
        for (var i = 0,len = uploadedFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
            var n = uploadedFiles[i].name;
            var s = uploadedFiles[i].size; 
            var t = uploadedFiles[i].type;
        alert("size  "+uploadedFiles[i].s)

                        }
    });

});
```

it shows me **size undefined** in `alert("size  "+uploadedFiles[i].s)` although in `alert("length" + uploadedFiles.length)` it's printing me the number of the uploaded files , so why i'm getting this`undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert("size  "+uploadedFiles[i].s)
```

should be

```
alert("size  "+uploadedFiles[i].size)
```

or

```
alert("size  "+s)
```

Be sure to add server-side validation.

Comment: ya you are right , how i missed that !! anyway is the server validation is a must ? i already validated the files in the client side

Comment: @Sherif Client side validation can be tampered ,to ensure double check server side Valid. should be in place